# Retrieve all profile metadata for comparison with vscode

Tags: profile, vs-code

Is it possible to retrieve all profile metadata (e.g. every custom object, field, page layout, record type, etc...) in vscode?

I tried using the org browser and don't see a profiles folder.  I tried using the Salesforce Package.xml generator extension but it only seems to pull in permissions related to other objects in the retrieve request.

So, does anyone know a way to retrieve everything or pull a complete profile?  My ultimate goal is to compare two profiles so we can start reducing our number of unnecessary profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to get every information about the profile, you have to create a package.xml file where you have to mention all the metadata for which you want to see the profile permissions. The below package.xml file contains custom objects, applications, tabs and profile. The profile metadata file will have information about user permissions, custom object field permissions, custom tabs and application permission. You can extend it to whatever you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <types> 
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types> 
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
<version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

My retrieved profile metadata file looks like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">        
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__Insights</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__Work</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>false</custom>        
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Validation_Control__mdt.isActive__c</field>
        <readable>false</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>Account__c</object>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>Order__c</object>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>Product_Family__c</object>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
        <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <allowRead>true</allowRead>
        <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
        <object>Product__c</object>
        <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
    </objectPermissions>
    <recordTypeVisibilities>
        <default>false</default>
        <recordType>Knowledge__kav.Country_sac</recordType>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </recordTypeVisibilities>
    <recordTypeVisibilities>
        <default>true</default>
        <recordType>Knowledge__kav.Worldkey</recordType>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </recordTypeVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>Account__c</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>Apex</tab>
        <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>Product_Explorer</tab>
        <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>Product_Family__c</tab>
        <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>Product__c</tab>
        <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>Pub_Sub</tab>
        <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>UirecordApi</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>Wire</tab>
        <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>X3rd_Party_Libs</tab>
        <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>Your_Bike_Selection</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <userLicense>Salesforce</userLicense>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ActivateContract</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ActivateOrder</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ActivitiesAccess</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AddDirectMessageMembers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AllowUniversalSearch</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AllowViewKnowledge</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ApexRestServices</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ApiEnabled</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ArchiveArticles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AssignPermissionSets</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AssignTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>AuthorApex</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>BulkMacrosAllowed</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CanInsertFeedSystemFields</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CanUseNewDashboardBuilder</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CanVerifyComment</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChangeDashboardColors</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterEditOwnPost</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterEditOwnRecordPost</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterFileLink</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterInternalUser</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterInviteExternalUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ChatterOwnGroups</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ConnectOrgToEnvironmentHub</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ConsentApiUpdate</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ContentAdministrator</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ContentWorkspaces</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ConvertLeads</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateCustomizeDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateCustomizeFilters</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateCustomizeReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateDashboardFolders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateLtngTempFolder</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreatePackaging</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateReportFolders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateWorkBadgeDefinition</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CreateWorkspaces</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CustomizeApplication</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>DataExport</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>DelegatedTwoFactor</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>DeleteActivatedContract</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>DeleteTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>DistributeFromPersWksp</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditActivatedOrders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditBillingInfo</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditBrandTemplates</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditCaseComments</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditEvent</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditHtmlTemplates</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditKnowledge</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditMyDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditMyReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditOppLineItemUnitPrice</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditPublicDocuments</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditPublicFilters</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditPublicTemplates</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditReadonlyFields</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditTask</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditTranslation</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EmailMass</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EmailSingle</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EnableCommunityAppLauncher</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EnableNotifications</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ExportReport</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>GiveRecognitionBadge</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ImportCustomObjects</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ImportLeads</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ImportPersonal</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>InstallPackaging</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>LightningConsoleAllowedForUser</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>LightningExperienceUser</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ListEmailSend</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageAnalyticSnapshots</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageAuthProviders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageBusinessHourHolidays</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCMS</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCallCenters</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCases</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCategories</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCertificates</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageContentPermissions</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageContentProperties</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageContentTypes</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCustomPermissions</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCustomReportTypes</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageDashbdsInPubFolders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageDataCategories</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageDataIntegrations</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageDynamicDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageEmailClientConfig</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageEntitlements</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageExchangeConfig</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageHealthCheck</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageHubConnections</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageInteraction</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageInternalUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageIpAddresses</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageKnowledge</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageKnowledgeImportExport</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageLeads</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageLoginAccessPolicies</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageMobile</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageNetworks</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManagePackageLicenses</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManagePartners</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManagePasswordPolicies</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageProfilesPermissionsets</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManagePropositions</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManagePvtRptsAndDashbds</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageRecommendationStrategies</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageRemoteAccess</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageReportsInPubFolders</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageSearchPromotionRules</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageSharing</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageSolutions</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageSubscriptions</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageSynonyms</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageUnlistedGroups</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>MassInlineEdit</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>MergeTopics</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ModerateChatter</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ModifyAllData</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ModifyDataClassification</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ModifyMetadata</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>NewReportBuilder</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>Packaging2</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>Packaging2PromoteVersion</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>PrivacyDataAccess</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>PublishArticles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>PublishPackaging</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>PublishTranslation</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>RemoveDirectMessageMembers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ResetPasswords</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>RunReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ScheduleReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SelectFilesFromSalesforce</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SendSitRequests</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ShareInternalArticles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ShowCompanyNameAsUserBadge</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SolutionImport</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SubmitForTranslation</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SubmitMacrosAllowed</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SubscribeDashboardRolesGrps</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SubscribeDashboardToOtherUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SubscribeReportRolesGrps</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SubscribeReportToOtherUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SubscribeReportsRunAsUser</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SubscribeToLightningDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>SubscribeToLightningReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>TraceXdsQueries</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>TransactionalEmailSend</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>TransferAnyCase</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>TransferAnyEntity</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>TransferAnyLead</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>UseTeamReassignWizards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>UseWebLink</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewAllData</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewAllUsers</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewArchivedArticles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewDataAssessment</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewDataCategories</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewDataLeakageEvents</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewDraftArticles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewEventLogFiles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewFlowUsageAndFlowEventData</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewHealthCheck</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewHelpLink</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewMyTeamsDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewPublicDashboards</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewPublicReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewSetup</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewUserPII</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>WorkCalibrationUser</name>
    </userPermissions>
</Profile>
```

Comment: Okay, so the only way is to create a package that retrieves all metadata, essentially?

Comment: Hi @jameskbw, there is already a package.html in the source code under Manifest folder. You only need to edit that file base on what resource you want to retrieve from the org. After updating the file, save it. Then right-click in package.html and click SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org.